# change background -image whit html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background-image

I want to put this image as a background under the div in which appears the writing G.E.D S.A.L.C
but it does not work .. although I have tried with CSS and even forcing it all with this:

```
<body bgcolor="blue" background="images/sfondo.png">
```

THIS IS THE CODE :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
     header('location: ../index.php');
    }else
    {
    
?>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>G.E.D.</title>
  <link href="../paginaIniziale/css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
   .bgimg-1{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("images/sfondo.png");
    min-height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="blue" background="images/sfondo.png">
  <div class="w3-top">
   <div class="w3-bar w3-padding w3-card" style="background-color: #ffc107">
    <h1>G.E.D. - S.A.L.C.</h1>
   </div>   
  </div>
   <div class="w3-display-middle w3-contener" >
    <a class="w3-center w3-padding-large w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide" style="margin-left: 22px;">Seleziona un operazione</a>
    <div class="w3-center" style="margin-top: 40px;">
     <a href="../pagineHtml/inserimento/inserimentoGenerale/inserimentoCantiere.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Milano </a>
     <a href="azioniVisualizza/sceltaCantiere.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Roma  </a>
     
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

and this is the image ... [BackGround IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYX0B.png)

the photo is placed in the right url

Does anyone know how to help me?
PS .. I admit that I have used a template
ahahaha

Comment: So where exactly is the element that the selector `.bgimg-1` is supposed to match then …?

Comment: i can't understand ..where i must put this selector ? @misorude

Comment: so i just paste url of the img into body `<body bgcolor="blue" background="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYX0B.png">` and all seems fine

Comment: Could be that it is just a mismatch on the image path. Can you confirm the image is actually loaded on request or if it hits 404? You can do so by Accessing `developer tools`, under the `Network` tab and refreshing your request

Comment: with the link it works but with the address of the folders, it does not work @Smollet777

Comment: As stated above, this can only mean one thing. You screwed up with the paths to the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already set bgimg-1 class. All you need to add the class to the body tag. Also, you don't need to force it using background ="images/sfondo.png" in the body tag.

```
  <body class="bgimg-1" bgcolor="blue">
```

Check the full code below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
     header('location: ../index.php');
    }else
    {
    
?>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>G.E.D.</title>
  <link href="../paginaIniziale/css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
   .bgimg-1{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYX0B.png");
    min-height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="w3-top">
   <div class="w3-bar w3-padding w3-card" style="background-color: #ffc107">
    <h1>G.E.D. - S.A.L.C.</h1>
   </div>   
  </div>
   <div class="w3-display-middle w3-contener" >
    <a class="w3-center w3-padding-large w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide" style="margin-left: 22px;">Seleziona un operazione</a>
    <div class="w3-center" style="margin-top: 40px;">
     <a href="../pagineHtml/inserimento/inserimentoGenerale/inserimentoCantiere.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Milano </a>
     <a href="azioniVisualizza/sceltaCantiere.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Roma  </a>
     
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply .. would you be so kind as to be able to put the buttons "Milan", "Rome" with a white background?

Comment: @AlexLogic I will but I want you to try it first. Please follow my instruction. Both buttons have a common class name w3-button. So all you need to add a background color for that class.

Comment: @AlexLogic here is the css you need add to achive the white background for the buttons. 
.w3-button{ background-color: #fff; }

Answer (score 0):

You created a CSS class name `.bgimg-1`, but you haven't used it anywhere. You likely want `<body class="bgimg-1">` in order to assign that CSS to it.

You should also make sure that file exists at the path specified. You can find out in Chrome dev tools by inspecting the `<body>` and clicking the background URL to open it in a new tab. Either an image will display, or you'll get a 404 error.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply .. would you be so kind as to be able to put the buttons "Milan", "Rome" with a white background?

Answer (score 0):

Add the class you created to the body element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
     header('location: ../index.php');
    }else
    {
    
?>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>G.E.D.</title>
  <link href="../paginaIniziale/css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
   .bgimg-1{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYX0B.png");
    min-height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body class="bgimg-1" bgcolor="blue" background="images/sfondo.png">
  <div class="w3-top">
   <div class="w3-bar w3-padding w3-card" style="background-color: #ffc107">
    <h1>G.E.D. - S.A.L.C.</h1>
   </div>   
  </div>
   <div class="w3-display-middle w3-contener" >
    <a class="w3-center w3-padding-large w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide" style="margin-left: 22px;">Seleziona un operazione</a>
    <div class="w3-center" style="margin-top: 40px;">
     <a href="../pagineHtml/inserimento/inserimentoGenerale/inserimentoCantiere.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Milano </a>
     <a href="azioniVisualizza/sceltaCantiere.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Roma  </a>
     
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply .. would you be so kind as to be able to put the buttons "Milan", "Rome" with a white background?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the attributes "background" and "bgcolor" are old methods and are non-conforming, so you should use CSS background / background-color properties instead.

Second, reading the comments it seems that your path is not correct.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply .. would you be so kind as to be able to put the buttons "Milan", "Rome" with a white background?

Answer (score 0):

please add the class attribute in the body tag 
like this

```
<body class="bgimg-1">
```

or just replace it with this

- with regards. kevil